# Is there a government database that tracks police-use of deadly force?

Tags: usa, police

I'm looking to find all casualties with officer involvement, whether they were detained, tasered, or shot. Is there any official government source that tracks this and makes the data public?

I see the [Bureau of Justice Statistics tracks this with their *"Arrest-Related Deaths"*](https://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=428) using "Arrest-Related Death Report (**CJ-11A**)". But I can't find the list of CJ-11A filings in the United States? Are they public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet; the [FBI announced they will launch one in 2019-01](https://www.apnews.com/3878b3206a0548409c3e4ee8bd6ae96b).
There are a number of fourth estate/civic activist databases, but no authoritative, government database, that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I do some research in this area. Albert has the right idea. There are at least three major community-based ones: The Counted, Mapping Police Violence, and Fatal Encounters. The best formal government database I am aware of is the [Violent Death Reporting System](https://www.cdc.gov/violenceprevention/nvdrs/index.html) - it has perks over National Vital Records, but until very recently not all states reported.